# Coq: how to prove existence of list having existence of an element?

Tags: coq

Say I have the axiom stating availability of an element:

```
Axiom FLP_Lemma3_p1: forall cfg, bivalent cfg -> exists msg, bivalent (run cfg [msg]).
```

How can prove the same property holds for an infinitely big list?

```
Theorem FLP_Lemma3: forall cfg, bivalent cfg -> forall m, exists s, length s > m -> bivalent (run cfg s).
```

Where `msg` is `nat`, `s` is a `list` of nats.

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer without knowing anything about bivalent, run, the type of cfg, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof:

```
Theorem FLP_Lemma3: forall cfg, bivalent cfg -> forall m, exists s, length s > m -> bivalent (run cfg s).
Proof.
  intros. destruct (FLP_Lemma3_p1 cfg H) as [msg B].
  exists [msg]. intros. apply B.
Qed.
```

The idea is to use your lemma to obtain the witness, but since the lemma provides `{msg | bivalent (run cfg [msg])}`, you need to break it into two pieces. You can do this immediately with `destruct`, or first introduce the witness with `pose proof (FLP_Lemma3_p1 cfg H) as L.` and then destructing `L`.

---

Now another note, this lemma you are trying to prove seems a bit useless.

Did you intend to prove:

```
Theorem FLP_Lemma3: forall cfg, bivalent cfg -> forall m, exists s, length s > m /\ bivalent (run cfg s).
```

Because this would be more interesting, but it not provable given your axiom, since you know nothing about the length of `msg`.

Comment: indeed, I misread his statement and read the ``/\`` instead of ``->`` because it seems more interesting :)

Comment: Yes, the useless lemma's proof is so short that it even fits in this margin: `intros; edestruct FLP_Lemma3_p1; eauto.`   :-)